# validate dob with age verification

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it so if someone is trying to fill in the form they must be between the ages of 15 to 80 but I am not sure how to use my date of birth to verify that the age is between 15 to 80. How would I go about doing this and how would I make sure the user that has entered their birthday is between the ages of 15 to 80?

```js
"use strict";
/*get variables from form and check rules*/
function validate() {
  var errMsg = ""; /* stores the error message */
  var result = true; /* assumes no errors */
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;

  //get varibles from form and check rules here
  // if something is wrong set result = false, and concatenate error message
  if (age <= 15) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 15 or older to fill out this form\n"
    result = false;
  } else(age >= 80) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 80 or younger to fill out this form\n"
    result = false;
  }


  if (errMsg != "") { //only display message box if there is something to show
    alert(errMsg);
  }
  return result; //if false the information will not be sent to the server
}


function init() {

  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform"); // get ref to the HTML element

  regForm.onsubmit = validate; //register the event listener 
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>The Virtual World</h1>
    <nav>
      <p class="menu"><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></p>
      <p class="menu"><a href="jobs.html#jobs">Jobs</a></p>
      <p class="menu"><a href="apply.html#apply">Apply</a></p>
      <p class="menu"><a href="about.html#about">About</a></p>
      <p class="menu"><a href="enhancements.html#enhancements">Enhancements</a></p>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="required">
    <h5>All fields with * are required</h5>
  </section>
  <form id="regForm" method="post" action="http://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Job Application</legend>
      <p><label for="JobID">*Job ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="JobID" id="JobID" maxlength="5" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$" required="required" /></p>
      <section id="choose">
        <h5>Please choose from QM593 or CS197</h5>
      </section>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>
        <p><label for="title">*Title:</label>
          <select name="title" id="title" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="title">Dr</option>
            <option value="title">Mr</option>
            <option value="title">Miss</option>
            <option value="title">Mrs</option>
            <option value="title">Ms</option>
         </select></p>

        <p><label for="firstName">*First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" required="required" />

          <label for="familyName">*Family Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="familyName" id="familyName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" required="required" /></p>

        <p><label for="midName">Middle Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="midName" id="midName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" /></p>

        <p><label for="dob">*Date of Birth:</label>
          <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" maxlength="10" size="10" required="required" /></p>

        <p>*Gender:
          <label for="male">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="male" required="required" />
          <label for="female">Female</label>
          <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="female" required="required" /></p>

        <p><label for="street">*Street Address:</label>
          <input type="text" name="street" id="street" maxlength="40" size="30" required="required" /></p>

        <p><label for="suburb">*Suburb/town:</label>
          <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" maxlength="40" size="20" required="required" /></p>

        <p><label for="state">*State:</label>
          <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="state">VIC</option>
            <option value="state">NSW</option>
            <option value="state">QLD</option>
            <option value="state">NT</option>
            <option value="state">WA</option>
            <option value="state">SA</option>
            <option value="state">TAS</option>
            <option value="state">ACT</option>
         </select></p>

        <p><label for="postcode">*Postcode:</label>
          <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" minlength="4" maxlength="4" size="10" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" required="required" /></p>

        <p><label for="email">*Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="30" required="required" /></p>

        <p><label for="number">*Phone number:</label>
          <input type="tel" name="number" id="number" minlength="8" maxlength="12" size="10" required="required" /></p>

        <p>Skill list:</p>
        <p><label for="C/C+">C/C+</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="C/C+" name="category[]" checked="checked" /></p>
        <p><label for="XML">XML</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="XML" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="Java">Java</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Java" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="Python">Python</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Python" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="SQL">SQL</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="SQL" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="PERL">PERL</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="PERL" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="MySQL">MySQL</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="MySQL" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="Windows">Windows</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Windows" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="UNIX">UNIX</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="UNIX" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="Linux">Linux</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Linux" name="category[]" /></p>
        <p><label for="other">Other Skills:</label> </p>
        <p>
          <textarea id="other" name="other" rows="8" cols="70" placeholder="Please write any other skills you may have here..."></textarea>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Application" />
  </form>
</article>
```

Comment: if you allow a minimum of estimation you can just return the year from the DOB, substract from current year and get the age. This will allow someone that has not turn yet to 15 (but will in that year) to register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the date will be separated by '/' just do it the old fashion way of splitting the string into 3 and creating a date object.

```
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value.split("/");

var date = new Date(dob[2], parseInt(dob[1]) - 1, dob[0]);
```

Then you can do your processing such as checking day, month, year to verify if they are between 15 and 80.

If you are not taking months and days into considerations then this simple if statement will fulfill the purpose.

```
var today = new Date();
var age = today.getFullYear() - date.getFullYear();

if(age >= 15 && age <= 80){
    // Between age ranges.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Date is library code yeah? If it is, is it possible to do it without it?

Comment: Date object is not a separate library, it's an object build into JavaScript already. My whole example doesn't rely on any external libraries.

Comment: One more question. I tried to verify that the validation would work but it doesn't seam to check it like i know i put in a dob that was over 80 but it allowed me to submit the form anyway. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know why, you need to debug your code, what input are you passing ? is it in format dd/mm/yyyy like your placeholder states? I have created a test jsfiddle and it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/kksc7gra/

Comment: alright thanks again, ill need to look through my code and try check if im missing something

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the age from dob, and after do the same validation you have done .

```
dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
dob = new Date(dob);
var today = new Date();
var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

if (age <= 15) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 15 or older to fill out this 
form\n"
    result = false;
} else (age >= 80) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 80 or younger to fill out this 
form\n"
    result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take in the string input of date, convert that to javascript's date object and subtract that from current time to check the age.

**Code snippet:**

```
var birthday = '1994-01-01';
var dateObj = new Date(birthday);
var diffTime = Date.now() - dateObj.getTime();
var diffAge = new Date(diffTime);
var age = diffAge.getFullYear() - 1970;
if(age < 15 || age > 80){
    //do whatever here
console.log("age is not in the range");
}
```

You can reduce this to one line too:

```
(new Date(Date.now() - (new Date(birthday)).getTime())).getFullYear() - 1970;
```

Comment: As @Adriani6 mentioned, you can take the new Date().getFullYear() to get current year too, and just subtract that from the birthday.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, in your answer you need to take into account the format of the date the OP is trying to use, seeing from the HTML DOM element it'll be dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks for that... missed the dd/mm part. But you can parse mm/dd/yyyy directly. :)

Comment: Of course you can, however months start with 0 index (0 for January and 11 for December) surely users won't be putting  that, so you need to account for that too (add an extra month to input) :)